# firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate() is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to take a Date() object and turn it into a proper Firebase timestamp for data. I found this function in the docs but it doesn't work for me. When I try to save as Date(date) it will save as a string instead of timestamp. any help?

```
           firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("articles")
          .add({
            url: url,
            archive: archive.docId,
            article: articleState,
            published: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date);})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to a Date object in order for it to become a timestamp.  The SDK will do that automatically.

```
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("articles")
          .add({
            url: url,
            archive: archive.docId,
            article: articleState,
            published: date
          })
```

It has to be an actual Date object for this to work.  For example:

```
let date = new Date()
```

If you're having problems creating a Date object (we can't see what you're doing), that sounds like a different problem entirely.

Comment: doh. I forgot Date() returns a string and new Date() is what I want. Thanks